# Select values by factor

Tags: r

I have a data frame which looks something like:

```
     a   b   c
1    1   2   3
2    3   4   5
3    4   5   2
4    3   5   6
.....
```

and I'm trying to make some kind of selector function which will create vector of values in a, b or c column based on a vector of column names, i.e. for the input vector:

```
c(a,b,c,b,...)
```

the output of the selector function should be:

```
c(1,4,2,5,...)
```

I can do it by looping trough rows or with nested ifelse but is there a better (more generic) way in case of more that few columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need row/column index to extract the values from the dataset i.e.

```
df1[cbind(1:nrow(df1), match(v1, colnames(df1)))]
#[1] 1 4 2 5
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c('a','b','c','b')
df1 <- structure(list(a = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 3L), b = c(2L, 4L, 5L, 5L), 
c = c(3L, 5L, 2L, 6L)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```

Comment: `df1[cbind(seq_along(v1), v1)]`